# Powershell. Deleting files without a recycle bin

Tags: powershell, recycle-bin

How to implement file deletion in Powershell without putting it in recycle.bin?
The current command moves files older than 30 days to the trash.

```
$int1 = 30
New-PSDrive -Name "E" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\Computer\c`$\Folder" -Persist
#FORFILES /p E:\ /s /m *.* /d -$int1 /c "CMD /c del /Q @FILE"
```

Comment: Look up Remove-Item instead of launching cmd shell.

Answer (score 0):

`Remove-Item` Deleting files without moving them to the Recycle Bin